# how to get the length of eyes and mouth using dlib

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, dlib, scikit-image

I am working on a project of yawn detection, i am using dlib and opencv to detect the face and landmark on a video.

I want to get the length of eyes and mouth.

this is what i have done till now

```
import sys
import os
import dlib
import glob
from skimage import io
import cv2
import time

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("")
    exit()

predictor_path = sys.argv[1]
faces_folder_path = sys.argv[2]

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi')

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)
win = dlib.image_window()

while vidcap.isOpened():
    success, image = vidcap.read()
    if success:
        win.clear_overlay()
        win.set_image(image)

        # Ask the detector to find the bounding boxes of each face. The 1 in the
        # second argument indicates that we should upsample the image 1 time. This
        # will make everything bigger and allow us to detect more faces.
        dets = detector(image, 1)
        print("Number of faces detected: {}".format(len(dets)))
        for k, d in enumerate(dets):
            print("Detection {}: Left: {} Top: {} Right: {} Bottom: {}".format(
            k, d.left(), d.top(), d.right(), d.bottom()))
            # Get the landmarks/parts for the face in box d.
            shape = predictor(image, d)
            print(shape)
            print("Part 0: {}, Part 1: {},Part 2: {} ...".format(shape.part(0),shape.part(1),shape.part(2)))
            # Draw the face landmarks on the screen.
            win.add_overlay(shape)
            win.add_overlay(dets)
        time.sleep(0.01)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vidcap.release()
```

please help me how to get the length of open eyes and mouth.

Comment: why not measure the distance between shape.part's ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this figure[image]

```
import Paths
import globals
from globals import ClassifierFiles
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import dlib
import math
import eyeCoordinates
import mouthCoordinates
from globals import Threshold
from globals import yawnFolder
import os
import openface
VIDEO_PATHS = []


readVideo('v.avi')#test video of faces



def readVideo(video):
    global no,yes
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector() #Face detector
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(ClassifierFiles.shapePredicter) #Landmark identifier
    face_aligner = openface.AlignDlib(ClassifierFiles.shapePredicter)

    u = 0
    while True:
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        if frame != None:
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            # clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
            # clahe_image = clahe.apply(gray)

            detections = detector(frame, 1) #Detect the faces in the image

            for k,d in enumerate(detections): #For each detected face
                shape = predictor(frame, d) #Get coordinates
                vec = np.empty([68, 2], dtype = int)
                coor = []
                for i in range(1,68): #There are 68 landmark points on each face
                    #cv2.circle(frame, (shape.part(i).x, shape.part(i).y), 1, (0,0,255), thickness=1)
                    coor.append([shape.part(i).x, shape.part(i).y])
                    vec[i][0] = shape.part(i).x
                    vec[i][1] = shape.part(i).y

                #RightEye and LeftEye coordinates
                rightEye = eyeCoordinates.distanceRightEye(coor)
                leftEye = eyeCoordinates.distanceLeftEye(coor)
                eyes = (rightEye + leftEye)/2

                #Mouth coordinates
                mouth = mouthCoordinates.distanceBetweenMouth(coor)

                print(eyes,mouth)
                #prints both eyes average distance
                #prints mouth distance
            break

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break



if __name__ == '__main__': 
    VIDEO_PATHS = Paths.videosPaths()
    init()
```

eyeCoordinates File

```
import distanceFormulaCalculator

def distanceRightEye(c):
    eR_36,eR_37,eR_38,eR_39,eR_40,eR_41 = 0,0,0,0,0,0
    eR_36 = c[35]
    eR_37 = c[36]
    eR_38 = c[37]
    eR_39 = c[38]
    eR_40 = c[39]
    eR_41 = c[40]
    x1 = distanceFormulaCalculator.distanceFormula(eR_37,eR_41)
    x2 = distanceFormulaCalculator.distanceFormula(eR_38,eR_40) 
    return ((x1+x2)/2)

def distanceLeftEye(c):
    eL_42,eL_43,eL_44,eL_45,eL_46,eL_47 = 0,0,0,0,0,0
    eL_42 = c[41]
    eL_43 = c[42]
    eL_44 = c[43]
    eL_45 = c[44]
    eL_46 = c[45]
    eL_47 = c[46]
    x1 = distanceFormulaCalculator.distanceFormula(eL_43,eL_47)
    x2 = distanceFormulaCalculator.distanceFormula(eL_44,eL_46) 
    return ((x1+x2)/2)



def eyePoints():
    return [36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47]
```

Mouth Coordinates File

```
import distanceFormulaCalculator

def distanceBetweenMouth(c):
    m_60,m_61,m_62,m_63,m_64,m_65,m_66,m_67 = 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    m_60 = c[59]
    m_61 = c[60]
    m_62 = c[61]
    m_63 = c[62]
    m_64 = c[63]
    m_65 = c[64]
    m_66 = c[65]
    m_67 = c[66]
    x1 = distanceFormulaCalculator.distanceFormula(m_61,m_67)
    x2 = distanceFormulaCalculator.distanceFormula(m_62,m_66)
    x3 = distanceFormulaCalculator.distanceFormula(m_63,m_65)   
    return ((x1+x2+x3)/3)



def mouthPoints():
    return [60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67]
```